# Background Task in ios is not executed and can not be debugged in physical device

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, background-task, bgtaskscheduler

I have a flutter project that contains some native code, in this case I have a background task using `BGTaskScheduler` (using native swift), ok now the problem is that the task is never executed and even simulating it using xcode with the option : Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch it nothing happens , let me show my code.

```
override func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
 ) -> Bool {
   initPlatformChannelAndCallMethod()
   .....
   .....
   self.registerTaskForLocation()
   GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
  return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

private func registerTaskForLocation(){
    self.isTaskRegistered  =   BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: 
 "com.myapp.bgtasklocation", using: nil) { task in
        let operationQuee = OperationQueue()
        print("Background executing")
        let locationOperation = BlockOperation {
            // execution of the main task
        }
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            locationOperation.cancel()
        }
        
        locationOperation.completionBlock = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success:  !locationOperation.isCancelled )
        }
        
        operationQuee.addOperation( locationOperation )
        
    }
    
    print("Task registered \(self.isTaskRegistered)")
    
}

private func scheduleThetaskRegistered(){
    let taskRequest = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com. 
 myapp.bgtasklocation")
    print("BGTask task requested with identifier")
    taskRequest.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2 * 60)
    print("BGTask added earliest start for bgtask")
    do {
        print("BGTask now will be submited")
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit( taskRequest )
    } catch {
        print("BGTask Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
    }
}
```

now so far the task is submited without problem and the print that is inside the
catch in scheduleThetaskRegistered method is not printed so I guess this task is
submited.
I already added the task identifier in info.plist and I enabled the background fetch in background modes.

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>com.myapp.bgtasklocation</string>
</array>
```

now when I move the app to background and start a simulation of background task in Xcode
using its debug mode: Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch.
Nothing happen and my code that is inside the BlocOperation is not triggered.

after trying some times at one moment I got this error after taping the option :
Simulate Background Fetch.

> [BackgroundTask] Background Task 54 ("Flutter debug task"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.

- Xcode Version 14.2
- Flutter 3.16.0
- Physical IOS version : 16.7.4
- Mac Monterrey 12.6.7

Comment: That debug menu option simulates the old style app refresh. To trigger a `BGAppRefreshTask` during debugging refer to this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting-and-terminating-tasks-during-development

Comment: thanks so much @Paulw11 I will read it.